# DataGrip tells me that comparing the value of a column to null is "suspicious". Is it a bad practice?

Tags: oracle, datagrip

I'm writing a constraint check for an Oracle table. In a constraint check I have a comparison to null:

```
CASE
    WHEN COL_A = 'A' AND COL_B = NULL THEN 'KO'
```

However, DataGrip highlights the words `COL_B = NULL` saying it's suspicious, and advises me to replace it with `COL_B IS NULL`.

Since I extensively use `= NULL` across my scripts, I wondered if it's a bad practice and a potential risk.

I searched and I found no result. I wonder why DataGrip is telling me it's **suspicious**, and why they did choose a so strong word.

Thank you

Comment: *Since I extensively use = NULL across my scripts* - either you are lucky and your columns are *not nullable or your tests are not complete;) It is **not** a bad practice, you should not *practice it at all*. Valid for `SQL` - in some programing languages is comparisong with `null`perfect s´possible.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber thank you, it actually works, so I suppose it's a matter of configuration or dialects. Btw now I understand why DataGrip shows me the warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the predicate `COL_B = NULL`  is perfectly well formed, but it is **never TRUE** (edited as noted by the *commentators*) - this makes the usage *suspicious* or meaningless.

**Example**

```
create table tab (col_b int);
insert into tab (col_b) values(null);

select count(*) from tab where col_b is null;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1
         
 
select count(*) from tab where col_b = null;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

Comment: This is not quite true. `COL_B = NULL` is not "always false" because then `NOT (COL_B = NULL)` would be true. You could say that it is never true, but it is equally also never false. SQL uses trinary logic and comparing `NULL` to anything will result in `NULL` (and not `TRUE` or `FALSE`).

Comment: `NOT (COL_B = NULL)` is `NOT (FALSE)` thus `TRUE`. I think it's someone would expect :)

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina You have misinterpreted what I said as `NOT (COL_B = NULL)` does **NOT** evaluate to `NOT (FALSE)` and then to `TRUE`; it evaluates to `NOT (NULL)` and then to `NULL` (which is not the same as `TRUE`). [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SevvJY1A)

Comment: The point is that the verbal explanation often goes back to the [logic of Aristotle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristotle), so saying *always FALSE* translated in `SQL logic` means `FALSE or NULL`. I edited the neither *quite true* nor *quite false* formulation, but the short answer is *never use `= NULL` in SQL*. @ChristianVincenzoTraina

Answer (score 2):

SQL (not just Oracle's dialect) uses trinary logic (as opposed to many languages that use binary logic) and there are three possible results from a comparison: `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `NULL` (unknown).

In trinary logic, when you use an operator (i.e. `=`, `!=`, `<`, `>=`, etc.) to compare `NULL` to anything then the output is `NULL` (and never `TRUE` or `FALSE`) since you are asking to compare an unknown value to something else and the result may or may not be true (or false), you just do not know even if you compare one unknown thing to another unknown thing.

Therefore, while `COL_A = NULL` is valid syntax, it will always evaluates to `NULL` and since it never evaluates to `TRUE` then your filter condition will never be true and that branch of the `CASE` expression will never be matched.

If you want to check whether a column is `NULL` (unknown) you need to use `IS NULL`.

```sql
CASE
WHEN COL_A = 'A' AND COL_B IS NULL THEN 'KO'
END
```